# My iPad only shows as a camera on my PC is there a free program to transfer files from iPad to PC

Tags: windows, windows-xp, ipad

How can I can transfer or sync files from my wife's iPad2 onto my computer (desktop)?

The desktop shows

> "Proeedure entry DeCoder point in dynamic link library kernel32/dll

error and I cannot get online. When I connect the iPad it shows only as a camera! So I cannot transfer the file to the PC to install it! I have iTunes installed on the PC but I cannot get iTunes to open? Should I just use the program you have mentioned on a Trial Basis only (I don't want to pay for it) or is ther another way? I have been using touch for my iPod would that do it.

Comment: _Should I just use the program you have mentioned on a Trial Basis only_ which program are you talking about? Who mentioned?

Answer (score 3):

Uninstall iTunes, reboot, and then reinstall it.

Comment: Thanks asthma i can't reinstall iTunes yet as I have no Internet connection due to the other problems that the Pc has Iwill do as you advise as soon. As I fix the dll problems on the computer thank you for your help Dasha

Answer (score 1):

You cannot send files from the Ipad to your PC, the iPad is locked down thanks to Apple.

I am aware of being able to transfer files from the Pc to the iPad using itunes, if the files are related to a certain app you have. I know this because I was able to transfer movies to the divx player I purchased for my iPad.

I would say you need to reintall itunes to be able to have a chance but then it would depend on what you are trying to send as their is no file explorer for the ipad.

Comment: Okay I get it now gotta luv apple thanks anyway michael Dasha

Comment: this is not 100% true.  You can generally access the DCIM folder for photos via Explorer.

Comment: You are correct in saying Photos can be seen in File Explorer but the user says he needed to transfer files and this is not possible. If you need this sort of functionality, you should look at tablets that are non apple.

Comment: @Michael yes- however, photos are 'files'- I was providing an exception to the 'answer's' blanket-statement with 'not 100% true'.  Hence me commenting and not answering.  Not all non-Apple are good- many Android tablets show up with restricted file-access.  You (@Dazza) need to do your research in models and facilitating Android apps.  Or, reinstall iTunes.  Unless you're in the jungle, someone can give you an installer.  You are posting a question here- begs the obvious question- 'no internet access?'.